# Need help writing mutation on AWS AppSync (GraphQL)

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have created this schema on GraphQL:

```
type Bird @model{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String!
    images: [String]
}

type Course @model{
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String!
    image: String
    birds: [Bird] @hasMany
}
```

Now I want to write the mutation for createCourse. I don't know how to include the array of Bird object in my course.

I don't know how to add Bird object here:

```
mutation MyMutation2 {
  createCourse(input: {image: "", name: "", description: ""})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a @hasMany directive referencing the Bird in a Course model, you should specify a @belongsTo directive in the Bird model.
Docs here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#belongs-to-relationship

So your Bird model should look like this (if you want a 1 to many relationship)

```
type Bird @model{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  images: [String]
  course: Course @belongsTo
}
```

This will create a new key for a Course in your Bird model.

Now, you can't add Bird objects when you are creating a Course. You need to create a Bird and there reference the id,in the new key created by @belongsTo, of the Course you want to relate to.